# How to convert a Python list of dictionary with same key value into dictionary with list of values

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I have a list of dictionary like this:

```
mylist = [
    {'survival': 124, 'organ': 'Stomach'}
    {'survival': 42, 'organ': 'Stomach'}
    ]
```

I want to change this into a dictionary with same keys to have list of value like so:

```
myDict = {
  "survival":[124,42],
  "organ":["Stomach","Stomach"]
}
```

Comment: Write a loop where you iterate over the dictionaries and append the values to lists in the result dictionary? What was the difficulty?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from collections import defaultdict

mylist = [
    {'survival': 124, 'organ': 'Stomach'},
    {'survival': 42, 'organ': 'Stomach'}
]

mydict_ = defaultdict(list)

for x in mylist:
    for k, v in x.items():
        mydict_[k].append(v)

mydict = dict(mydict_)
print(mydict)
```

result

```
{'survival': [124, 42], 'organ': ['Stomach', 'Stomach']}
```